# in PowerApps, new publisher keeps loading

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

when clicking on : New Solution > Publisher > New Publisher, the dialog keeps loading and stuck.

any solution for this?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache and cookies (for all time) once. Let me know if it works for you. Also check if you see any error messages in browser console.